# Can I use Mongodb's ObjectId string as a file/dir name?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, filesystems

I want to use ObjectId as a directory name for some related files on the server, just to keep every directory with a unique name.

However, I'm not sure if ObjectId will always be a valid file/dir name or not?
Can it contain any illegal symbols for file names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Mongodb on that.

Yes, it's legal for file names.

> The ObjectID is stored as a hexadecimal which will consist of the numbers 0-9 and letters A-F.